# How to create reusable client-side components in nextjs that allow interactivity?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

[Example nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2afj.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2afj.png)

I want to create the navbar referenced above in react and nextjs. The two buttons on the navbar should be a component that accept a prompt ('login' and 'sign up') and an onClick function so that the buttons can become truly reusable and interactive. The problem I'm having is that I need to turn the entire navbar into a client side component in order to send an onClick function from parent to child.

In my view, this clearly defeats the purpose of creating a boundary between server and client side components because eventually some leaf component that requires interactivity will cause the entire tree to have become a client component. I must be missing something...

Answer (score -1):

You can extract the buttons from the NavBar component and mark only the extracted component as a client component. You can learn more in the official [NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#moving-client-components-down-the-tree).

Here is an example:

`NavBar.tsx`

```
function NavBar() {
    return <>
        <p>Your logo</p>
        <NavBarButtons />
    </>
}
```

`NavBarButtons.tsx`

```
"use client";
function NavBarButtons() {
    return <>
        <button onClick={() => { }}>Button 1</button>
        <button onClick={() => { }}>Button 2</button>
    </>
}
```

Comment: Your "NavBarButtons" is not really reusable. The onClicks of the two buttons will always be the same regardless of where it is used.

For this to be reusable, the onclicks should be props which can be configured on a case by case basis, depending on where it is used.